# Is there any tracing in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a very large dependency tree and Unity is failing trying resolve a dependency somewhere in this huge dependency chain.  I'm having to manually look through all the dependencies to work out what might be missing, which is a huge task.

Unfortunately, unity only reports the item it's trying to construct in the exception it throws and gives no info about the route it has taken to get to that point.

Does Unity put out any tracing/logging info that might help me work out exactly what dependencies I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Tracing implemented in Unity.

The `ResolutionFailedException`, that is thrown by Unity when an attempt to resolve a dependency fails, contain all relevant information whether in its `Title`, `StackTrace` or `InnerException` property.

Normally does the most `InnerException` contain the root cause of the `ResolutionFailedException`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the dependency tree is so big and complex that there just isn't enough information in the exception to be of use.

Comment: @Magoo yeah its cumbersome, but the lowest InnerException should provide the information you need, cause its the root cause of the ResolutionFailedException.

Comment: I just checked again @Jehof.  The InnerException is null :(  I'm resigned to looking for the proverbial needle in a haystack now.  Thanks for your input.